# Remote queue manager connection with authentication

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I need to connect with the remote queue manager with user authentication 
(user id and password). 
I follow [How do I connect to a remote queue manager with WebSphere MQ Explorer?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHIhDJEQGGw) to add a remote queue manager. Here they mentioned about the user id and password under the specify user identification details. I didn't clear about it , which user is and password ?

I create a client java programme for accessing remote queue manager with authentication.

Please anyone guide on how to add a remote queue manager with user id and password and also how to define these values in the java client programme?

Comment: What version of MQ are you using?  If it is V8 then I recommend you look at this Redbook which gives information about authentication.  http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248218.html?Open

Answer (score 0):

If your queue manager is IBM MQ V8, the user ID and password you supply are either:-

- O/S user ID (and associated password) from the machine the queue manager in running
- LDAP user ID (and associated password) if the the queue manager is configured to use LDAP instead of O/S for password lookup.

If your queue manager is pre-V8 you need to use a security exit to check the user ID and password at the queue manager, so the user ID and password you supply will be entirely dependant on the exit and what it is written to use. In this case read the documentation that came from the vendor that produced the exit.